# css three column layout

Tags: css, border-layout

I am trying to set up a border layout with top, left, center, right, bottom. I have seen a few examples and tried them, but none of them seem to work. The main problem is with the left, center, and right columns. I can only get two divs aligned horizontally, the third always falls below the footer.  I need this to be resizable. Preferably the center pane will fill the full until the borders.

I have tried float left and float right but it didn't make a difference.

This is what I have tried so far.
    http://jsfiddle.net/xQVWs/2/

```
<body>
<div class="top-wrapper">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <header>
            header
        </header>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mid-section">
    <div class="left-wrapper">
        Left Pane
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
        Main pane
    </div>
    <div class="right-wrapper">
        right pane
    </div>
</div>

<div class="bottom-wrapper">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        footer
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `float:left` on the first two middle columns and a `float:right` on the third. I would put an `overflow:hidden` on the wrapper for the middle columns.

http://jsfiddle.net/zer6N/1/

```
.mid-section
{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height:1000px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.left-wrapper, .right-wrapper {
    background: #ffff00;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 21%;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
}

.right-wrapper {
    background:#efefef;
    float:right;
}

.main-content {
    background-color: black;
    width: 58%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: this is brilliant, I didn't think of making two of them float left. Thanks a lot, really cleaned it up nice. I'd been beating my head against this all day.

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with your site!